# why is scanf skipping an integer in an input txt file?

Tags: c++, scanf

I am trying to understand the procedure of scanf for an exam tomorrow. I cant for the life of me figure this out. Any help would be appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int sum()
{
  int r;
  int x,y;
  while ((r = scanf("%d,%d",&x,&y)), ((r >= 0) && (r < 2)))
  {
    char ch;
    scanf("%c",&ch);
  }
  return x+y;
}

int main()
{
  int x;
  x = sum();
  return 0;
}
```

the input.txt is:

`as23,rt12,67cd!x1,2`

When I run this program in gdb and put a break on

`return x + y`

x is printing x=12, and y is printing y = 67.

Why is 23 being skipped and not assigned to x, and why is 12 not being assigned to y? The loop is suppose to skip characters that are not integers such as "as" in the input.txt Even with a input.txt of `12,rt12,67cd!x1,2`

it is still skipping 12 being assigned to x. I am lost.

Comment: the first match of `%d,%d` for your input is `12,67`. Debug all calls to scanf.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because scanf() will only accept input that *exactly* matches the format string you gave it. In this case, the format string is saying: I want an integer that is immediately followed by a comma, which is then immediately followed by another integer.

The first thing in your input string that matches your first scanf() format string is "12,67", so your while loop will keep eating characters from your input stream until it comes across the "12,67" and then the first scanf() will successfully complete (and the `((r >= 0) && (r < 2))` condition will terminate the while loop).

Comment: Thank you so much. That makes a lot of sense. My teacher didn't really explain that. I have been learning python on my own and it is quite easy. My c++ professor in college is a genius but is not a very good teacher. He makes things very complicated and rarely gives out simple precise answers to questions. I took the online MIT intro to algorithms with python and even that was easier to understand than my community college professor. Oh well for those who went to college we all get those professors sometimes. Comes with the territory. I am thankful for stackoverflow for the help. Thank you.

Comment: Check my explanation again. I have edited it because I made a wrong assumption the first time so the new answer is more correct. This does kind of seem like a needlessly complicated example designed to trip up novices.